# Find Row Index in HTML Table Row DOM Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js, html-table

I have a table set up now in just Knockout and jQuery and I need to be able to find the row index of a row that is clicked for selection. I have it set up so that my table is populated by a Knockout observable array and my table row click events are handled by the following function:

```
$("#table tr").live("click", callbackFunc(position));
```

But as you can see I need the position of the row that is clicked on to be passed in to the function for it to work. The last thing I tried was:

```
$("tr",$(this).parent("#table")).index(this)
```

But that only returned -1.

Anyone know of a solution?

Comment: Does `callbackFunc(position)` return a function? If not, you're invoking `callbackFunc` when the click handler is bound, not when the click event is fired.

Comment: I should have clarified! Yes it does return a function, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do something like this in jquery

```
$("#table tr").on("click", function()
{
$(this).prevAll("tr").size();        //this will return all tr before current tr 
                                     //i.e current row index
```

}
);

As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
$("#table").index(this)
```

Hope this will fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should use .index() method of jQuery like this

```
$("#table tr").live("click", callbackFunc);

function callbackFunc(){
   var index = $(this).parent().index(this);
}
```